# How to specify LMER model to customize different predictors on random intercepts and slopes

Tags: lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, growth-model

I'm trying to specify a longitudinal growth curve model (mathematically defined in Bollen & Curran's 2006 Latent Curve Model book, Chapter 6).

Here's some brief theoretical context for this study: In short, we want to measure peoples' longitudinal changes in relationship satisfaction over time, and how these vary based on peoples' intervention group membership (we had 3 experimental intervention groups -- a control group, and 2 different intervention groups). The interventions started 2-weeks into the study, so we want to measure the intervention effects on peoples' changes over time (slopes) -- not their starting values (intercepts).

In short, I'd like to specify a growth curve model in which there are 2 dummy-coded grouping effects on the random slopes, but these dummy codes should NOT effect the random intercepts (due to the fact that the interventions began 2-weeks after the starting date of the study). The correct model is hand-written in [image: the attached photo]: 'Linear Model Version 2'.

I've only been able to specify the preliminary (incorrect model) also illustrated in the attached photo as 'Linear Model Version 1', which specifies grouping effects on both the random slopes and random intercepts:

```
Mod1 <- stan_lmer(RelationshipPMean ~ Period*(Group2+Group3) + 
    (1 + Period | PID), data = dat1)
```

To clarify -- can anyone help me specify grouping variables that effect only the random slope, and NOT the random intercept, while still allowing the random slope and intercept to correlate? Thank you for your time!

Comment: I'm still having a little trouble understanding this, but I *think* something like `~ ... + (1|PID) + (0 + Period*Group2*Group3|PID)` should work ...

Comment: Thank you! This is almost exactly the model that I want, except that I would still like the intercept and slope to correlate in this model -- do you know how to maintain this correlation?

Comment: does `(1+Period:Group2:Group3|PID)` do what you want?

Comment: That is close, thank you! I finally figured out what I was looking for: Mod1 <- stan_lmer(RelationshipPMean ~ 1 + Period + 
                    Period:Group2 + Period:Group3 + 
                    (1 + Period | PID), data = dat1)

Comment: you could answer your own question, if you think you've succeeded